# OCI.DLL error connecting to Oracle DB in Impromptu 7.5

Tags: oracle11g, business-intelligence, cognos, impromptu

I am trying to connect to an Oracle 11 database in Impromptu 7.5 but I am getting the below error. This is generated when trying to open a catalogue and when the option for 'connect to database' is selected:

> Error number -45:
>   DMS-E-DBDLL_NOTFOUND, The dynamic link library 'OCI.DLL' could not be located in the search path or one of its dependent dynamic link libraries failed to load

I am using Impromptu version 7.5 on a Windows 7 64 bit machine attempting to connect to an Oracle 11g database. I have the Oracle 11g client installed on my machine and the correct service name configured for my database in Net8 Assistant.

I have also checked the C:\oracle\product\11.2.0\client_1\BIN directory and OCI.DLL exists there. This directory is also referenced in my PATH variable.

I am able to connect to the database without issue using Aqua Data Studio v12 but it just seems to be Impromptu 7.5 that doesn't like it.

Any ideas anyone? Could it just be a compatibility issue? Thanks

Comment: Here's an idea: use procmon to monitor where it's looking for that file. procmon generates a lot of data but you can see exactly what and where your impadmin.exe process is looking for the DLL.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I've run procmon and it's looking for and finding OCI.DLL in the Oracle directory, however it is also looking in all sorts of other places and returning a 'NAME NOT FOUND' error. I don't see why some of the locations it's looking in are relevant however it is looking in C:\Windows\sysWOW64 and returning NAME NOT FOUND. I'll try copying it to that location and trying again

Comment: That's normal for it to search all over the place and return a NAME NOT FOUND error. As long as it finds it eventually. So then next one to download is... `dependency walker`. You can load your DLL and see if it is missing a dependency (which is the other half of your error message.

Comment: Do you use 64-bit Oracle client? If so, try to uninstall it and install 32-bit driver. Cognos products does not like 64-bit clients.

Comment: Thanks for your replies, Ran, this fixed the problem. I was running 64Bit Oracle client. Installed 32Bit and it now works fine

Comment: if you use 64-bit pc, oracle doesn't compatible with it. Oracle doesn't find oci.dll file in 64-bit.

Therefore, you can try to change oracle home on the top. As a result of that, home path will change.

At least, I solved that error with changing path.